# Call a function inside an underscore template using backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Just a thing I try to do that would really simplify my life right now.

How can I do that :

This is my view in app file

```
    window.ArtView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template:_.template($('#art').html()),
        render:function (eventName) {
            var output="blablbla";
            $(this.el).html(this.template({"output":output}));
            return this;
        }
    });
    ...
    // function that I would like to call
    function callFunction(){
        console.log('it works!');
    }
```

Template in index.html

```
<script type="text/tempate" id="art">
        <div data-role="header" class="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#" data-icon="back" class="back ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            callFunction();
            <% console.log(output) %>
        </div>
</script>
```

How can I call callFunction() inside my template or something alike ?

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Keep your templates dry. Your templates should not contain any logic.

Comment: True, but I think that there are usecases for calling functions from templates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe you can call functions within the template as long as the object for the template has the function.

```
render:function (eventName) {
    var output="blablbla";
    var data = _.extend({"output":output}, callFunction);
    $(this.el).html(this.template(data));
    return this;
}
```

then in your template:

```
<%= callFunction() %>
```

Answer (score 6):

this is how I did it , it works fine.

```
template: _.template(templateText , {
            imports : {
                check :function (val){
                    // blah blah
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
```

then in your html template

```
<%= check('value') %>
```

Comment: Just to note, it is Lodash feature, Underscore 1.9.1 does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong. Think about the template as a string, html markup. You get it and replace some parts of it with the actual data. If you want to do some DOM manipulation they should be made after that. Let us know what you want to do in callFunction and we may guide you to the right place for that logic.

Comment: Yes you are right, I thought of it. I would like callFunction() to be a call of jPlayer (a jquery media player), which needs a source (url.mp3). The source's url is in my output. A little tricky isn't it ?