# Calling a function inside underscore template defined in Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to call a custom function inside a underscore template, however I get an error: testFunction not defined.

In my backbone View:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.testFunction = function (x) {
        alert("Hello " + x);
    }
}

render: function() {
    var data = _.extend({"output":output}, this.testFunction);
    $(this.el).html(this.template(data));
    return this;
}
```

In my template I call the test function:

```
<%= testFunction(10) %>
```

But I get an error testFunction is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) doesn't work like that, it needs 2 or more objects, and the keys will be merged. *It looks like you probably took that snippet from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18962123/1218980), but it's incorrect and/or outdated.*

> **extend** `_.extend(destination, *sources)`
>
> Shallowly copy all of the properties in the **source** objects over to
>   the **destination** object, and return the **destination** object. Any
>   nested objects or arrays will be copied by reference, not duplicated.
>   It's in-order, so the last source will override properties of the same
>   name in previous arguments.
>
> ```
> _.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
> => {name: 'moe', age: 50}
> ```

This would work:

```
_.extend({ output: output }, { testFunction: this.testFunction });
```

But a better way in this simple case would be to avoid `_.extend` altogether.

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
    output: output,
    testFunction: this.testFunction
}));
```

In a real life situation, you may want to use the view [context (`this`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) within the function. To do this, you would need to use [`.bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on the function when passing it to the template.

```
this.$el.html(this.template({
    output: output,
    testFunction: this.testFunction.bind(this)
}));
```